# Tab Navigator performance issue using redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation, redux-saga, tabnavigator

I am using `React native 0.50.4`, and `react navigation 1.0.0-beta.19`. I have a perfomance issue. I am using `Tab navigator` with 4 tabs basically each a form (max 11 fields) 
I have hooked up all the forms fields (all 4 tabs)  in redux states. so that the data is available when save happens at the last Tab.

Now the user can navigate to this `Tab navigator` when editing (by clicking button edit), on each tab's `componentDidMount`. I am dispatching action creators , that populates the states of each field. and then in render method populating field values (from mapStateToProps).

> NOTE: no data is being fetched from server here, the data is being passed through navigation state when clicking the Edit button

The performance issue is where when the `Edit button` is clicked ,  it takes few seconds before performing navigation (on real device, on emulator no performance issue). I tried to have loading state to initiate before performing all the other dispatches in `componentDidMount` but still , the navigation doesn't happen immediately (meaning it does not navigate and show loading state and once everything ready , just show)

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    props.initialLoader(); // STATE HERE LOADING: TRUE
}

componentDidMount(){
 if (this.props.navigation.state.params){
   const userData = this.props.navigation.state.params.userData;

   this.populateOperation(userData).then(() => {
      this.props.dismissLoader(); // LOADING: FALSE
   });

 }
}
populateOperation = (userData) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve(
            this.props.inputChanged(userData.emailAddress),
            this.props.addressInputChanged(userData.address),
            this.props.addressContInputChanged(userData.addressCont),
            this.props.cityInputChanged(userData.city),
            this.props.stateInputChanged(userData.state),
            this.props.postalCodeInputChanged(userData.postalCode),
            this.props.countryInputChanged(userData.country == ''? 'Country' : userData.country),
            this.props.phoneInputChanged(userData.phone),
            this.props.mobilePhoneInputChanged(userData.mobile),
            this.props.linkedInInputChanged(userData.linkedIn),
            this.props.twitterInputChanged(userData.twitter),
        );
    });
}

render(){
   const {...} = this.props.formState;
   return(
     <KeyboardAwareScrollView
       style={outerContainer}
       keyboardOpeningTime={100}
       extraScrollHeight={5}
     >
    {
       loading ?
       ... // SHOW LOADING
       :
       ... // FORM
    }

   );
}

function mapStateToProps (state){
    return {
        formState: state.contactReducer
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
       ...
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContactTab);
```

The above code is sample of one of the Tabs.

> NOTE: when using redux-thunk performance was really bad, it took up to 7 second maybe more to navigate, after switching to redux-saga, it became faster, taking 3-4 seconds to navigate
>   NOTE: The tab navigator is nested in a top level stack navigator.

Answer (score 2):

Why dispatch 11 actions when you could just dispatch one action to update the store?

Every dispatch causes a potential re-render which is probably the cause of your performance issues.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment on the question.